# Replacement of bottom part of Sharan 2nd row seats

Tags: seat

We have a VW Sharan 2014 and the 2nd row window seats have integrated booster seats. This car has been involved in an accident and it's been written off.
We are looking into buying a Seat Alhambra 2015 (same body and interiors) and were wondering if we could save the bottom part of the Sharan seats and have them inserted in the Alhambra... 
Many thanks,
MAria